# .htaccess rewrite rule - matching and forwarding image requests with certain character in the name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently have the following .htaccess file in my ../test/media folder to redirect all jpgs to another server

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule /([^./]+\.(jpg))$ http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/$1
```

This works great thanks to help on this site.

BUT, i have a caveat. if the image being requested has a filename like *_p.jpg then I would like it directed to another location on the target server but without the '_p' part.

eg

http://blah/media/catalog/product/3/8/3848038_5856.jpg gets redirected to http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/3848038_5856.jpg currently and that works.

However if i request http://blah/media/catalog/product/3/8/3848038-3565_p.jpg then I want it to redirect to http://www.example1.com/img/norm/high/848038-3565.jpg rather than http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/848038-3565.jpg

Is this even possible??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
RewriteEngine on

# First we redirect *_p.jpg files
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule /([^./]+)_p\.jpg$ http://www.example1.com/img/norm/high/$1.jpg

# ... and then other jpgs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule /([^./]+\.jpg)$ http://www.example1.com/img/gallery/$1
```